# Angular directive doesn't work for elements added to the DOM by jquery plugin

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm creating a fall back image directive that looks like this http://plnkr.co/edit/wxy4Sp2K02iXoQNsvkah

```
angular.module('directives').directive('myDirective', function() { 
   return {
     restrict: 'C',

     link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
       console.log('linking');
     }
   }
});
```

My directive doesn't work for elements that are added to the DOM by the typeahead.js plugin (https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js).

```
<div class='tt-suggestion'>
   <div><span class="my-directive">bla</span></div>
</div>
```

I guess it's because Angular is not informed about the elements that are added by jQuery and hence it doesn't invoke the directive. How do I notify Angular of these changes?

Comment: I really do not understand you question but you will use scope.$apply() to notify angular about changes occurred out of angular env. Could you post a sample (plunk or similar)

Comment: Here's the plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/wxy4Sp2K02iXoQNsvkah. Notice how the directive 'myDirective' is never linked in the template (the link function is not called when the results are rendered).

Comment: I think your concept is wrong and you should follow advice Rishul Matta gave you in answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Angular compile service to do this: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Basicly it works like this: 
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = $compile("")($scope);

Comment: how do I access $compile from jQuery land?

Comment: You could execute your jquery code inside an angular-controller

Answer (score 0):

ideally you shouldnt be mixing jquery and angular because they both are based on different philosophy.

jquery-- is event driven i.e. have event listeners which cause changes to model and then the programmer has to code numerous lines to change the view i.e. changing css,text etc

angular-- woo hoo! just change the model which is binded to $scope and :) your view is automatically updated

to automatically react on changing of such events angular has a compiler which studies entire html code before the app is loaded so even if there is a template which you might use later you must enclose it in   so that angular compiles this so that all the special angular directive and controller perform as expected even when you remove or add templates to the dom.

here you are using typehead.js and jquery to manually manipulate the view which is against angular philosophy because when you do such maipulation angular compiler wouldnt be aware of it as it runs only when the app is initialized. Thats why before appending you should use  **$compile** to make the angular compiler aware of this template .

in your case i would suggest the typehead present on this url 
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/